# error message not displaying on mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to validate something but It always returns a success result. I wonder what's wrong with my codes.

```
      INSERT INTO playlist_details (playlist_id,filename,image_id,transition,timeframe,userid,update_date)
    VALUES (i_playlistid,i_filename,i_imageid, i_transition, i_time, i_userid,i_date);

    SELECT booking_id INTO v_booking_id FROM staging_table WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid LIMIT 1;

    SELECT num_of_spots INTO v_spots FROM booking_sum WHERE booking_id = v_booking_id;

    SET v_allowed_time = v_spots * 30;

    IF ((SELECT SUM(timeframe) FROM playlist_details WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid) > v_allowed_time) THEN

    SET o_success = FALSE;
    SET o_message = 'You exceeded the time allowed with your booking';

     SELECT playlist_id,filename,image_id,transition,timeframe,userid FROM playlist_details
    WHERE userid = i_userid;

    ELSE

     SELECT playlist_id,filename,image_id,transition,timeframe,userid FROM playlist_details
    WHERE userid = i_userid;

    SET o_success = TRUE;
    SET o_message = 'Success';

    END IF;
```

Comment: why you except something if you do not output or select anything? you can do return o_success` or something like this at the end of proc

Comment: I just want to check if the sum of the timeframe at my playlist_details table exceeds the allowed time, and if it does, it will return an error message.